# windows 7 takes more than 2 hours to boot

Tags: windows-7

I am using `Dell Latitude E6420`.

2 days back while using it Windows crashed 4-5 times, displaying Blue Screen error with error codes  IR`QL_NOT_LESS_OR_EQUAL, PAGE_FAULT_IN_NONPAGED_AREA.`

after that it showed Hard Disk problems. Since then, it takes almost `1.5-2 hours` to completely boot the Windows.

Also after the boot process is completed, none of the application is working fine. Everything hangs for unlimited time period.

If anyone knows any solution for this, please guide me. (facing great trouble these days :( )

Answer (score -1):

1. Check your ram.

   - Open your PC. and take one of the ram out(if it's possible. ) turn it on. check if problem still exists. then put it back in. take another one out.. check. rinse and repeat :D
2. Check your HDD.

   - Take your HDD out. put it in another pc as data.. check for HDD errors. do it for the other one.. rinse and repeat.
3. Check your CPU.

   - Well.. you COULD try switching it with another one.. but if in my case if your problem didn't get resolved with 1,2 i'd get another PC.. or .. try reinstalling windows on a DIFFERENT HDD